# Is the existence of morality compatible with necessitarianism?

Tags: ethics, necessity

This is somewhat related to my previous question, here: [Is the nature of morality counterfactual?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/102087/is-the-nature-of-morality-counterfactual). If morality is counterfactual, what would a necessitarian point of view imply about it? Since necessitarians do not believe in counterfactuals, would that mean a necessitarian does not believe in the existence of morality? This does not mean a necessitarian would behave immorally, just that there is no such thing as morality, because morality is a counterfactual theory. But has any philosopher argued that the existence of morality is compatible with necessitarianism?

Comment: Well, there probably aren't many necessitarians around these days. But you can still do counterfactuals if you are a necessitarian, because you don't need "possible worlds" to frame counterfactuals. You just need to trace the consequences of a causal model. See Judea Pearl.